# How to use jetty's RewriteHandler?

Tags: url-rewriting, jetty

I am using Jetty as my web server, and I want to do the url rewrite stuff.
Do you know how to use `RewriteHandler`?

For example:
the url `localhost/path1/123.html` should be rewritten by Jetty to `localhost/path1:id=123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is here - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler

If you've followed the documentation and aren't getting the result you want, then please provide a description of what you tried, and what result you got.

Comment: This is much more up-to-date: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http-handler-use-util-rewrite-handler